# trying to get value from array by json_encode Illegal string offset

Tags: php, json

Here is what I have tried:

```
$arrayToJson = '{"doctype":"invrec","docnum":3006}';
$arrayToJson = json_encode($arrayToJson);

print_r($arrayToJson['docnum']);
```

The result is: "

Answer (score 4):

You've made a mistake with how you are trying to convert the object to an associative array in your PHP.

You should be using `json_decode` to decode the string to an object.  Additionally, you want it to be an associative array so must specify `TRUE` for the second parameter of `json_decode`:

```
$arrayToJson = '{"doctype":"invrec","docnum":3006}';
$arrayToJson = json_decode($arrayToJson, TRUE);

print_r($arrayToJson['docnum']);
```

OUTPUT:

```
3006
```

For your reference, the documentation for `json_decode` is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to *decode* your JSON, not encode it a second time.

And secondly, your JSON contains an *object*, so you either need to use `$arrayToJson->docnum` here to access the property, or you need to decode it with the second parameter of `json_decode` set to `true`, so that the result will be converted into an array.